# Maths puzzle on equidistant points

Tags: geometry

Can four points be equidistant with each other ? and what is the highest number of points that can be equidistant with each other ?( In two-dimension)

Comment: Do you want distinct points?

Comment: Also, where do the points come from?

Comment: The answer depends on the dimension of your space. For four points take the vertices of a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron). For more, take the simplex in higher dimensions.

Comment: 4 distinct points , ( points equidistant like - all the three points in equilateral triangle are equidistant)

Comment: @clayd7 in 3-dimentions?

Comment: is it possible in two dimension?

Comment: I do not believe so

Comment: It isn't possible in 2D. Assume you have 4 such points, remove one at random and you get an equilateral triangle. The 4th point must then lie on the intersection of the three circle centered at vertices of the triangle, and radius length the side of the triangle. That particular intersection is always empty.

Comment: A good technical tool for these questions is Cayley Menger determinant.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the number of dimensions of your space. For four points take the vertices of a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron).

**General**: For $n+1$ points take the [$n$-dimensional simplex](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_(Mathematik)) in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Its vertices are equidistant. When you want the points to be distinct, then this is the best you can do. This means that in two dimensions there are at most three pairwise equidistant (and distinct) points possible which form an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Since 4>2+1 then this cannot be done because the maximum number of points is the dimension of the space +1.  This can be proved by induction on $n$ as is done here.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30270/maximum-number-of-mutually-equidistant-points-in-an-n-dimensional-euclidean-spac

Answer (score 0):

Three points on the vertices of an equilateral triangle are equidistant with each other.

Any extra point inside or outside of this trinangle will not be in equidistant with other points.
Therefore the answer is $NO$.
[image]